# Mollification of functions in $L^2(0,T;H^1)\cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1})$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))\cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain.

I know that (eg. from Wloka or Hunter's PDE notes) that there is a mollification sequence $u_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R};H^1)$ such that  $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^2(0,T;H^1)$ and $u_\epsilon' \to u'$ in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

This sequence is smooth only in time. Is it possible to get a sequence from mollification that is also smooth in space?

Maybe I can approximate each $u_\epsilon(t)$ for each $t$ by spacial mollification? References would be appreciated.

Comment: I bet that the obvious approach of taking $$u_\epsilon(t, x)=\iint u(t-t', x-x')\zeta_\epsilon(t')\zeta_\epsilon(\lvert x'\rvert)\,dt'dx'$$works. (This, by the way, is exactly what you suggest, that is, taking the spatial mollification of the time mollification).